# how to create typescript definitions for function that extend objects

Tags: typescript

there are function in 3rd party libraries that extends objects to add to them more functions. e.g. [seamless-immutable](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable)

I want to create definition file for such a library. I thought something in the line of

```
interface ImmutableMethods<T> extends T{
    set?<U>(key: string | number, value: any): T | U;
    setIn?<U>(keys: Array<string>, value: any): T | U;
    ...
}
function Immutable<T>(obj: T, options?): ImmutableMethods<T>
```

Then I will be able to declare my own types as:

```
interface Type1 {prop1, prop2}
interface Type2 {propOfType1: ImmutableMethods<Type1>}
var immutableType2:Type2 = Immutable(...)
```

And then I'll have the Immutable's function on all my objects.

But the problem is that the line `interface ImmutableMethods<T> extends T` gives me an error "An interface may only extend a class or another interface"

Is there a way to declare that T is an interface, or a whole other way to get this extending behavior?

Comment: I don't see why you want to use `extends T` on your interface. Can't you just extend from `Immutable<T>`

Comment: I don't want to couple my business logic interface with implementation details of the library I'm working with. Another thing is that there is a need to pass arrays and mapping so instead of just writing  x: ImmutableMethods<Array<MyInterface>>, I need to somehow create a new kind of Array object.

Comment: FYI, I posted an issue on the seamless-immutable repo regarding typings: https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable/issues/108

Answer (score 2):

You can use intersection types to attain this behavior. Define an interface for the extra functions and define a type that is T & Interface. My modifications to your code:

```
interface ImmutableMethods<T> {
    set?<U>(key: string | number, value: any): T | U;
    setIn?<U>(keys: Array<string>, value: any): T | U;
}
type ImmutableExtended<T> = ImmutableMethods<T> & T;

interface Type1 { prop1: string, prop2: string }
interface Type2 { propOfType1: ImmutableExtended<Type1> }
var immutableType2: Type2 = ...;
```

The `ImmutableMethods<T>` interface defines the functions involved. The `ImmutableExtended<T>` type is the interface we actually want to use for the extended objects, though of course you can name these interfaces whatever you like.